# Make an <a> html element execute a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to load content of a main `<div>` when user clicks on an `<a>` element.

This is the menu item structure, with the `<a>` element and some non-working code to try to further explain the question:

```
                <li>
                    <a href="#" onclick="menu_foo()">
                        <span>Foo Menu</span>
                    </a>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function menu_foo() {
                            $('#main_panel').load('/foo');
                        }
                    </script>
                </li>
```

The items of the menu are generated dynamically, hence the < script > has been located next to the `<li>` item.

The specific question is related to how to make an `<a>` element launch a JavaScript function.

Comment: What is shown should work assuming path is correct and id=main_panel exists. Any errors in browser console? Inspect request in browser dev tools network for issues

Comment: Something is unclear. Your code already invokes menu_food when clicking the anchor. Maybe what you need more is to call for stopPropagation. Otherwise, the function gets invoked, which is what you are asking for.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, main_panel did not exist. I was so focused on the menu that I forgot to add it. It actually works

Comment: More efficient way is use one event handler and use attributes on the `<a>` to determine what to load based on the one that was actually clicked

Comment: @charlietfl That sounds quite interesting, like menu_click('foo','/foo') ?

Comment: You shouldn't be misusing `a` element for this. Use a more appropriate element like `button`.

Comment: @connexo I agree with that, but I am reusing an existing theme/template and I prefer to keep the existing structure to preserve all the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to generate dynamically script. Just generate `a` with `href` that will link to the page you want to load.

```
<a id="load" href="/foo1">
     <span>Foo Menu</span> 
 </a>

<script>
    $("#load").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault ();        
         $("#main_panel").load($(this).attr("href")); 
     });
<script>
```

Comment: This is approach is useful too.

Comment: I am selecting this as a valid answer although all comments are useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use a jquery click handler and load the file on clicking. $("a") selects all anchors so you might want to attach a class or id on the a tag.

```
                <a id="one" href="#" onclick="menu_foo1()">
                    <span>Foo Menu</span>
                </a>

                <a id="two" href="#" onclick="menu_foo2()">
                    <span>Foo Menu</span>
                </a>

                <a id="three" href="#" onclick="menu_foo3()">
                    <span>Foo Menu</span>
                </a>

    $('#one').click(function(){
        $('#main_panel').load( '/foo1' );
    });

    $('#two').click(function(){
        $('#main_panel').load( '/foo2' );
    });

    $('#three').click(function(){
        $('#main_panel').load( '/foo3' );
    });
```

Comment: Not likely OP wants to load same path each time

Comment: The jquery approach is by far much more elegant, but I am generating the menu dynamically, hence I find easier to group the handler inside the <li> item. Generated code might seem too verbose with html and javascript mixed but in the template looks concise and good as everything is in the same place.